# How can map assign value to _id in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code 1 is a sample code from webpage. In order to simplify the question, I make the Code 2

In Code  2, the snippet `var _id: Long by map` make me confused ,  the val map is `MutableMap<String, Any?>` and _id is `Long`, why can the map assign value to _id ?

**Code 1**

```
class CityForecast(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>, val dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var city: String by map
    var country: String by map

    constructor(id: Long, city: String, country: String, dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>)
            : this(HashMap(), dailyForecast) {
        this._id = id
        this.city = city
        this.country = country
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
class CityForecast(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>, val dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var city: String by map
    var country: String by map   
}
```

**To Grzegorz Piwowarek** , is the code 3 right?

**Code 3**

```
val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>
var _id: Long by map
map=hashMapOf("_id" to 123)  
println(_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's one of the language features - Delegated Properties.

Kotlin does not really expose class fields by default but properties which are usually backed by fields but can be backed... by a map as well.

```
val id = CityForecast(hashMapOf("_id" to 123), emptyList())._id
println(id) // 123
```

but if you try to run:

```
CityForecast(hashMapOf("_id" to 123), emptyList()).city
```

you will get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Key city is missing in the map.
```

Comment: Thanks!  After I pass the val hashMapOf("_id" to 123),  will "var _id: Long by map" get value from map?

Comment: @HelloCW yes, exactly - try running my example

Comment: Does it mean that the snippet  var _id: Long=hashMapOf("_id" to 123) OK?

Comment: @HelloCW well, no. Here you are simply trying to assign a map to a long

Comment: @HelloCW no, you need to initialize a map on the spot in this case